# How can I find what APIs I'm accessing?

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm having some issues that are causing me to get denied on Apple Reviews.

Apple is stating that I am using their ScreenTime API in an unapproved way. The problem is, I cannot find anywhere in my code that I have referenced any of the documented ScreenTime calls or methods. I haven't even imported any ScreenTime-related frameworks (at least not that I can tell based on Apple's docs).

Is there a way to find this reliably via Xcode? Apple won't give me a reference to where they are finding my usage of the ScreenTime API so they're quite unhelpful there.

Comment: Likely third party packages check their documentation or stop using them.

Comment: I am not using any third-party frameworks or packages. Everything is vanilla SwiftUI.

Comment: I would definitely push back and ask for clarification from Apple. Sometimes they're just wrong. There's definitely no definitive way to know what Apple is looking at other than asking them and them telling you. I would look in "Embedded Frameworks" and make sure you're not linking it if you're not using it. (And explain to them that you don't even link it.) Best of luck; these reviews can be very frustrating. But don't assume App Review is right. They make a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, @RobNapier. I suspected this was the case but as a novice iOS developer who is submitting my first app, I am completely ignorant. The reviewer did respond "We still see that the binary has enabled support for ScreenTime API, however there are not ScreenTime API features within the app." but when I look through Xcode, I just cannot find anything where I have enabled it anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally enabled Family Controls. Go to your project's settings for your target, and select "Signing & Capabilities." See if "Family Controls" is enabled, and remove it if so. For more details about this system, see [Screen Time Technology Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screentimeapidocumentation/).

Comment: Okay so I use Managed Settings on my app so that I can change settings within it and I see that appears to be a Screen Time Technology Framework. Do you think Apple will be sufficiently pacified if I describe my use of that?

Comment: Make sure that you're assigning all required Info.plist fields and correctly implementing the `AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization` block. I recommend re-watching any WWDC videos that walk through correct setup. (Probably https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110336/ and any previous ones it references)